# how can i read /dev/sda1?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this in the Python REPL:

```python
file = open('/dev/sda1','rb')
```

However, I am getting this error:

> **Traceback (most recent call last):**
>   File `<stdin>`, line 1, in `<module>`
>   **`IOError`: [Errno 13]** *Permission denied: `/dev/sda1`*

How do I gain access to `/dev/sda1`?

Comment: my goodness man, click the little check mark and accept some answers!

Answer (score 5):

You likely have to be `root` to read `/dev/sda1`. You usually can run `sudo` to run things as `root`. For example, to run `myscript.py`:

```
sudo python myscript.py
```

Or to run the REPL:

```
sudo python
```

You must be a member of the appropriate group to use `sudo`. Additionally, your system may not have `sudo`. If your system does not have `sudo`, you may have to use `su`. If your system does not have `su`, you may have to log in as `root`.

For more information on `sudo`, type `man sudo`.
For more information on `su`, type `man su`.

Comment: Be very careful with this, though... ...you're just one character away from `file = open('/dev/sda1','wb')`!

Comment: @Johnsyweb: True, but that won't clear it; it's a block device.